# Adding Property to Documents Where Target Property is an Array Not Working as Expected

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying to add a property to every element in an array for a property on every document in a collection. After doing some research, this seems like the way to go:

```
db.customers.update(
   { "subscriptions": { "$elemMatch": { "subscriptions._id" : { $exists: true } } } }, 
   { "$set": { "subscriptions.deleted": false } },
   { "multi": true }
)
```

What I assume this will do is find every element on the "subscriptions" array where an "_id" prop exists (which will be every one). It will then add the "deleted" property to each one of those elements -- and do that for all documents since "multi" is set to "true".

But this doesn't seem to work as expected. My result is:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

This is what the data looks like:

```
{
  _id: 333,
  nameFirst: 'John',
  nameLast: 'Smith',
  subscriptions: [
     { _id: 555,
       someProp: 'abc'
     },
     { _id: 556,
       someProp: 'def'
     },
  ],
  email: 'john@email.com'
}
```

... and this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
{
  _id: 333,
  nameFirst: 'John',
  nameLast: 'Smith',
  subscriptions: [
     { _id: 555,
       someProp: 'abc',
       deleted: false // This is the prop I want to add to each element
     },
     { _id: 556,
       someProp: 'def',
       deleted: false // This is the prop I want to add to each element
     },
  ],
  email: 'john@email.com'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) (positional filtered) operator in MongoDB 3.6 to update multiple array elements specifying matching condition:

```
db.customers.update(
   { }, 
   { "$set": { "subscriptions.$[cond].deleted": false } },
   { "multi": true, arrayFilters: [{ "cond._id": { $exists: true } }] }
)
```

For lower MongoDB version you can use the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator which can replace existing collection with aggregation result. Try:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            subscriptions: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$subscriptions",
                    as: "sub",
                    in: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: { $gt: [ "$$sub._id", null] },
                            then: { _id: "$$sub._id", someProp: "$$sub.someProp", deleted: false },
                            else: "$$sub"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "customers" }
])
```

Using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to overwrite existing `subscriptions` and `$gt` to check if field exists.

Comment: Thanks, but in our case, we're not yet on 3.6. Any options for 3.2?

Comment: There might be an option but I need to know why you want to do that with `multi: false` without specifying document `_id`. It seems like you'll update only single more or less random document.

Comment: I updated my syntax to target the "deleted" property within "subscriptions".

Comment: Okay, but as far as I understand your goal is to update only some elements of `subscriptions` array. Is that correct ? Does this apply to single document or entire collection ?

Comment: Sorry. It should be "multi: true". I edited that above. Every single element in the array for that property, for every single document in the collection should have this "deleted" field added and set to `false`.

Comment: So, there is a problem with this 3.2 approach. It does add the desired field, but, in the process, it wipes out any other properties on the array element. So, in the case of the example I had above, the `someProp: 'def'` gets wiped out.

Comment: You need to specify all those existing properties inside `in` section like I did for `someProp` from your sample model. You could use `$mergeObjects` to avoid that but it's not available in 3.2

Comment: Right. That occurred to me afterwards. In my case that would be a lot of props to add in, but I guess that's the only viable method prior to 3.6. Thanks.